# How to disable default URL mappings for some actions

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller, grails-3.1, urlmappings.groovy

I'm using Grails version 3.1.12.

I want to disable some default URL mappings for actions in order to manage them manually. For example, given the controller:

```
class MyController {

    myAction() {
        render('Hello')
    }
}
```

This action maps by default to `my/myAction`, however I want to disable this mapping and use a custom one like this one defined in UrlMappings.groovy:

```
static mappings {

     "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    '/myCustomAction'(controller: 'my', action: 'myAction')
}
```

The `/$controller/$action...` mapping ships by default when creating the Grails project for the first time and provides the default convention which I still want for some other actions, however I want to exclude the default mapping for `myAction`. I have tried using the `excludes` setting in UrlMappings.groovy:

```
static excludes = ['/my/myAction']
```

However, the endpoint `my/myAction` keeps responding to the default mapping.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: how is your controller mapping to ```my/myAction```? should not it be ```myController/myAction```?

Comment: @DegenSharew the convention in Grails is `controllerName/actionName` where the name doesn't contains the "Controller" part of the class name. See http://docs.grails.org/3.1.12/guide/single.html#urlmappings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route `my/myAction` is being generated by the default `/$controller/$action` mapping. As such you will need to edit the constraints section of that mapping in order to exclude your controller, something like this should work (albiet some what ugly):

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
    constraints {
        controller(validator: { return it != 'my'})
    }
}
```